# visual studio debugger graphical visualizer c++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, charts, debuggervisualizer

are there any good tutorials or training for writing custom visualizers with c# for debugging c++ code?

I found an [example](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Writing-graphical-debugger-a17e3d75) but the code does not work with visual studio 2015.
Took some time trying to debug but I can't see the content of the variables representing the debugger information.

I do not mean debugger information formatting like natvis, I need a graphical output of the variable data like [ArrayPlotter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RodneyThomson.ArrayPlotter), but for my data structures and I don't like to write my array of structs to float arrays.

Comment: You would need to modify the debugger to use the Visualizer.

Comment: I can see parts of the data, like the variable name, when debugging the visualizer in c# but I don't know how to access encapsulated structures. The example code does wrong accesses to the given structures.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Graphical Debugging](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamWulkiewicz.GraphicalDebugging) extension?

The code is open and available [at GitHub](https://github.com/awulkiew/graphical-debugging) so you can fork it and add support for any C++ types you like. If you only need to represent your structs as 2d points you do not even need to fork anything, just define point classes in XML file. If you have any questions just create an issue at GitHub.